# save the output of command prompt to a file

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, jql

I am trying to execute a series of commands in a `cmd.exe` shell from within Java and pipe the output of these commands to a file. Here is the code I've written:

```
Process process = rt.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd C:\\Temenos\\ModelBank-R15-TAFJ\\T24\\Env\\MB\\Agents && C: && Environment.bat && DBTools JQL LIST-ITEM F.SPF \">D:\\test.txt \"");
```

If I run `DBTools JQL LIST-ITEM F.SPF`, I can see output on the console, but I want to save the output to a file. When I add `> D:\\test.txt`, I see that a `test.txt` file is created in `D:\`, but it is blank.

Please if anyone can help me out in this, as this very crucial for my project.

Comment: *"Please don't close this post."* will not help if you do not ask a proper question

Comment: Why do you have a `cmd /c` running `cmd.exe` again with `/K`?

Comment: You could also try piping the output to a file within Java.